# Отображение контент iframe в другом div

Tags: javascript

Имеется структура

```
<body>
<iframe id="player"> </iframe>
<iframe id="content"> </iframe>
</body>
```

iframe#player:

```
<audio> </audio>
```

iframe#content:

```
<div class='radio'><div>
```

Как можно получить весь контент из `iframe#player` и записать его в div `radio`? При том, что в `iframe#play` элементы управления плеером, которые должны работать в `div.radio`, и динамический контент, меняющийся через какое-то время. Т.е. получается, что `iframe#play` будет скрыт, а в `iframe#content.radio` будет отображаться все, что происходить в скрытом iframe.

Comment: а зачем скрывать фрейм и показывать его содержимое в другом?

Comment: @Grundy дело в том, что этот iframe с плеером всегда должен находиться на главной странице. А так как он iframe, он при прокрутке ездит за скролом. В общем дурная система из-за которой теперь нужно выкручиваться, подобными извращениями.

Comment: _А так как он iframe, он при прокрутке ездит за скролом._ - вот это совсем не понял. добавьте более развернутый пример кода

Comment: На странице 2 фрема: в одном контент, во втором плеер. При клике по ссылкам во фрейме контента, должен происходить переход на эти страницы в пределах этого фрейма. При этом фрейма с плеером это никак не касается. По уму это делается ajax`ом. Но так уже нельзя. В следствии всего этого на странице где 2 фрема, при прокрутке страницы фрем с контентом скролится,  а фрейм с плеером ведет себя как fixed, всегда двигается за скролом.